# .htaccess url rewrite for subdomain in CakePHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

In CakePHP, I'm adding my url rewrite exception for a subfolder this way:

In `/public_html/subdomain/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In `/public_html/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So now how can I make an exception and at the same time constantly point
`http://domain.com/subdomain/some.php`
to 
`http://subdomain.domain.com/some.php` ?

Note that I also want to install another CakePHP application in this `subdomain`

Comment: You generally don't need to modify that file at all. Note that you're using a development install, which is not recommended you should be using [a production install](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production).

Comment: I'm using cakephp 2.x, not sure if that has a development/production install difference as well. By the way, I just found that I've type the wrong thing, it should be `/public_html/subdomain/.htaccess` for the first part.